# $\langle v, v \rangle \geq 0$ meaning in inner product space.

Tags: linear-algebra

In Linear Algebra Done Right: https://zhangyk8.github.io/teaching/file_spring2018/linear_algebra_done_right.pdf

Inner product space is defined as a vector space V together with an inner product $V \times V \to \mathbb{F}$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.
The inner product must satisfy $\langle v, v \rangle \geq 0$.

How would it be defined if $\langle v, v \rangle \in \mathbb{C}$?

In the definition of norm, they defined norm as $||v|| = \sqrt{\langle v, v \rangle}$. From another source, norm is defined as a nonnegative real value function, that implies $\langle v, v \rangle$ must be nonnegative real.

Additionally, they defined a positive operator as a linear map from $V$ to $V$ that is self-adjoint and $\langle Tv, v \rangle \geq 0 \text{ } \forall v \in V$

How would it be defined if $\langle Tv, v \rangle \in \mathbb{C}$?

Thank you!

Comment: In the context of complex numbers, $z \geq 0$ generally means that $z$ is real-valued and nonnegative. That's the intended meaning for $\langle v, v \rangle \geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks, personally I think it is not satisfying since they never defined $\geq$ in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: When the book says ${\mathbb F} =  {\mathbb C}$, it means that $\langle u, v\rangle \in {\mathbb C}$ in general, but still $\langle v, v\rangle \in {\mathbb R}$.

Comment: @khanh The author does define it. See the second-to-last bullet point on page 165 of your PDF. "If $\lambda$ is a complex number, then the notation $\lambda \geq 0$ means that $\lambda$ is real and nonnegative."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sometimes an annoying convention, but for complex numbers when we write (for instance) $z\ge 0$, we really mean that $z$ is actually a positive real number. In this case, note that the standard Hermitian inner product on $\Bbb{C}^n$ given by $\langle z,w\rangle =\sum_{i=1}^n \overline{z}^iw^i$ has
$$
\langle z,z\rangle =\sum_{i=1}^n \overline{z}^iz^i=\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert z\rvert^2\in \Bbb{R}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

By definition it means that for every $v\in V$, $\langle v,v\rangle\in\Bbb{R}$ and $\langle v,v\rangle\geq 0$; or simply, because the set $[0,\infty)$ is a subset of $\Bbb{C}$, we can just say $\langle v,v\rangle\in [0,\infty)$. It is common to avoid saying all of this, and just write $\langle v,v\rangle\geq 0$.

Here's another long-winded way of saying it. The inner product on a complex vector space is a function $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:V\times V\to \Bbb{C}$. From this function we can define the "quadratic function" $Q:V\to\Bbb{C}$ defined as $Q(v):=\langle v,v\rangle$. Now although $Q$ has the complex numbers $\Bbb{C}$ as the target space, what the axiom is requiring is that the **image** of the function $Q$ is actually a subset of $[0,\infty)\subset \Bbb{C}$.

It's the same story with $\langle T(v),v\rangle$.